# Automatically capture file names and use them for output files in R

Tags: r

Recently I needed to write reproducible R code for reading a batch of .csv files and then outputting each of them with the same name. For example,

```
    filenames <- list.files(path="G:\\test")
    filenames
    [1] "mydata1.csv" "mydata2.csv" "mydata3.csv"........."mydata100.csv"
length(filenames)
100
```

For each of these 100 files, I need read the file in, reformat it, and then use `sink()` to output a .txt file under the same name. (Thanks to @Frank for helping me a lot with the code!) For instance, I read in the first .csv file `mydata1` under the folder "G:\test" and I want to use the follwing code to output a .txt file with the same name: `mydata1`.

```
 mydata1
     value group treatment
    1   39.7     A         1
    2   53.5     A         1
    3   51.1     A         1
    4   67.8     A         1
    5   84.8     B         1
    6   80.3     B         1
    7   79.6     B         1
    8   84.3     B         1
    9   31.0     C         2
    10  32.0     C         2
    11  33.0     C         2
    12  34.0     C         2
    13   1.0     D         2
    14   2.0     D         2
    15   3.0     D         2
    16   4.0     D         2
    printables <- lapply(
    split(mydata,mydata$treatment),
     function(t)
     split(t,as.character(t$group)))
    sink("G:\\test\\mydata1.txt")
    for (t in seq_along(printables)){
     for(g in seq_along(printables[[t]])){
     print(printables[[t]][[g]],row.names=FALSE)
     cat('\n')
    }
    cat('\n\n')
    }
    sink()
```

So for the 100 .csv files under the same folder, how can I write reproducible code to automatically capture each file name and then put the captured name into the `sink()` to output a txt file with the same name?

Comment: Get the bare file name with `gsub(".csv", "", filenames)`. Then when you write with `sink()`, use `paste0(<output from gsub>, ".txt")` as the new file name.

Comment: and you might to want to change directories to new one say output before inadvertently overwriting the input files or change the name of the file (but I don't think you want that). you can change directories in `R` with `setwd("new directory")`, use that before the the first sink statement

Comment: Thank you ,all~! Your suggestions help me figure it out~!! So appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. As Alex A. mentioned, you can get the prefix of the filename with grep (or in this case sub) and use that in the new filename.

I've made a simpler working example. There are two csv files with the structure below. These are read in and then in a loop printed to sink output. I've omitted your code for simplicities sake, but assuming that's working it should be simple to substitute in.

file1.csv:

```
structure(list(file = c(1L, 1L), value = 1:2), .Names = c("file", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

file2.csv:

```
structure(list(file = c(2L, 2L), value = 3:4), .Names = c("file", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

R script:

```
setwd("path\\to\\files")
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv$")
files

for(i in 1:length(files)){
  test.data <- read.csv(file = files[i], header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  filenm <- sub("csv", "txt", files[i]) # get rid of csv suffix and replace with txt
  print(filenm) #check, to make sure the above is working
  sink(file = filenm, type = "output")
  # your code here
  print(head(test.data))
  sink()
}
```